# Python Dataframe - Calculate the mean of groups and store

Tags: python, dataframe

I am coding in Python. Dataframe *full_df* has features: *building_id*  and *log_price*. I want to calcute the mean of *log_price* grouped by *building_id* and a new feature *mean_log_price* in *full_df* created, storing the the mean of the *log_price* according to its *building_id*.

I have following code:

```
    full_df['mean_log_price'] = full_df.groupby(['building_id'],as_index=False).agg(np.mean)['log_price']
```

However, when I look into *full_df*, some values for *mean_log_price* are NaN and some values are incorrect after I do some checking. Why does this happen and what are alternative methods? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there less unique `building_id`s than rows? Then the column length of `mean_log_price` will be shorter than the column length of `full_df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*agg* will change the length of the result and destroy the index as well, so you will not get the correct the result by assigning a smaller object to a larger data frame. Here you need `transform`, which keeps the length and index of the Series so it can be assigned back to the data frame:

```
full_df['mean_log_price'] = full_df.groupby('building_id')['log_price'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: @CharlieG Thanks. Appreciate it.